# pinescript, date/day formatting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm fairly new to pinescript and I'm having a couple of issues.

I am attempting to project a vertical line with a label ahead of the current price which needs to appear each day and or on specific days of the week.
So far I have this (below) which works for the best part but it expires after the time has past. I then need to adjust the 'date' to the next day so I can see the lines again.

So my questions are:

1. How do I set the date to be 'daily' or on specific days of the week (Monday, Thursday, etc.) so the lines draw each day / each specific day automatically - rather than inputting a single date which expires when it passes?
2. How do I position the 'label' to appear the bottom of the screen and to the left of the line?

Many thanks in advance!

```
//@version=4 

t1 = timestamp("2022-02-17T04:30:00-05:00")

if barstate.islast

    line.new(t1, 0, t1, 1, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.both, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 000, 80), style=line.style_solid, width = 1)

label.new (t1, 0, text="label", xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 000, 80), style=label.style_label_right, textcolor=color.white)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dayofweek` to find out if it is a new day and what day it is.

Coming to your second question, you already know the x and y positions of your line. Use those values when you create your label and add them as an offset. You cannot exactly place your labels on the bottom of the chart. You should find the optimum y value using the price.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_new_day = dayofweek[1] != dayofweek
is_tuesday = is_new_day and (dayofweek == 3)     // 1: Sunday

bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(is_tuesday ? color.red : na)

var label label1 = na

if is_tuesday
    label1 := label.new(bar_index-5, low - 2000, text="Tuesday")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
For the label, I was plotting CLOSE -30 - I was hoping there was a way to place it at the bottom to keep it tidy.
Regarding individual day's "new line", I have a series of times that I need to convert into vertical lines so they appear on a Monday, then a differnt series of times for the 
Tuesday, and so on. The following week these times (already set for those days) need to automatially appear again at their set time.
The code I have works but the DATE expires. So what I'm looking for 
is for the DATE to be the DAY so it repeats every week.
Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I just needed to change the format for referencing the time to `timenow`.

```
year = year(timenow)
month = month(timenow)
dayofmonth = dayofmonth(timenow)

t00 = timestamp("UTC", year, month, dayofmonth, 23, 30, 30)

if barstate.islast
    line.new(t00, 0, t00, 1, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.both, color=#ffffff, style=line.style_dashed, width = 2)
```